# CSS Pseudoelement containing alternate text is not working in IE

Tags: html, css, sass, accessibility, wcag

I am working on creating the custom checkbox having custom check mark, which comes from svg (base64 encoded), that I have provided as pseudoelement. 
Also need to add accessibility for this checkmark which is provided as an alternate text.
Below is the syntax - 
content: url("base64 encoded svg") / "alternate text";

However above syntax works properly in Chrome, but it does not work in IE. 
Need help on this  issue.

I have attached the code snippet.
This below code snippet works properly in chrome but not in IE (the check mark is not shown in IE if it is having alternate text in content property)

```css
#square{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}


#square:before{
   display: block;
   content:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') / "";
   
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work on W10 Firefox here on SO either (for me, anyway) when I run the code snippet. Also, shouldn't you be using `background-image` instead of `content`? For as far I know `content` is reserved for text (or unicode characters)...

Comment: The component is already build as of new that how is requirement, but only thing pending is implementing alternate text for this content property. 
This is the link of how to add alternate text in css content https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content
But however this syntax is not working in IE only running in Chrome
This is the ex text in it "content: url("http://www.example.com/test.png") / "This is the alt text";"

Comment: Well, I didn't know that `url()` could be used. However, I checked the MDN link and scrolled down to 'Image combined with text' example. The example ICO is not show in my recent FF either, only the example link, with *and* without privacy tools enabled. Scrolled further down to 'Images and element attributes' examples which do show the ICO/PNG. Difference: ** / " MOZILLA: "** behind **`url()`** in the first example (as you are using  / "" ). Maybe that's the fix: remove / ""...

Comment: @user1441238, Look at [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#Browser_compatibility) for alternative text. It won't fly in FF, IE and Safari. Do you really need an empty string as the alt text?

Comment: Also you can refer this https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#alt

Comment: While in the W3 specs, it doesn't mean it is supported by browser vendors (as @Kosh stated)... Fix: loose the alternative text (or use `background-image` as I suggested before).

Comment: @Kosh yes that is requirement, however is there any other way to implement accessbility for this custom checkbox, main thing is to prevent the image from being read by screen readers, thats why provided alternate text in content property, as it is a custom checkbox

Comment: @RenevanderLende agree not implemented by old browser, only thing is background image might not be used because its not my requirement of some others.
The main thing is how we can skip the screen reader reading this content ie svg checkmark, so that why alt text was provided, however it is not working, any alternative

Comment: You did not mention any screen-reader requirements, however, why should any reader mention 'ICON' when it's missing anyway, a vision impaired person won't miss it it the first place. However, if you must, I'd say use `background-image` with some `area` attribute.

Comment: Yes sorry didnt mention screen reader, mentioned accessiblity instead.
@RenevanderLende, Kosh thanks for providing the alternative, will look forward implementing it, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rene suggested, you might leave `content` empty, and set the checkmark as `background`:

```css
#square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#square:before {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M21.652,3.211c-0.293-0.295-0.77-0.295-1.061,0L9.41,14.34  c-0.293,0.297-0.771,0.297-1.062,0L3.449,9.351C3.304,9.203,3.114,9.13,2.923,9.129C2.73,9.128,2.534,9.201,2.387,9.351  l-2.165,1.946C0.078,11.445,0,11.63,0,11.823c0,0.194,0.078,0.397,0.223,0.544l4.94,5.184c0.292,0.296,0.771,0.776,1.062,1.07  l2.124,2.141c0.292,0.293,0.769,0.293,1.062,0l14.366-14.34c0.293-0.294,0.293-0.777,0-1.071L21.652,3.211z"/></svg>') no-repeat 0 0 / cover
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: Read @user1441238 last comment about  a *screen-reader* (and my reaction to that). `background-image` (as you posted here) with `aria` attribute seems to me the way to go.

Comment: @RenevanderLende, thanks for your coments, since the actual requirements are not really clear to me, I'd prefer to stop at this point.

Comment: @Kosh the main thing is the content: url(svg encode) is not ignored by screen readers, thats why it it was suggested to add as alternative empty "" text in the form "url(svg encode) / "" to prevent image being announced by screen reader

Comment: May be I cannot give further more explaination

Comment: in the above example this **will not be read by screen readers**. After rereading all of the comments I believe this is exactly what you want to achieve. `content` is read by some screen readers as it is assumed it contains important text, whereas `background` is assumed to be decorative and is ignored by screen readers. The new syntax for `content` with a forward slash is for if you **want to provide alt text** which it appears you do not.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie, exactly.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie yes but the new syntax of content with slash (i.e alt text) is not supported by old browser, hence later I implemented the solution by setting the background image as said by Kosh and  Rene van der Lende and keeping the content blank. Thanks